# Will performing a "System Repair" in Windows 7 require re-installing my applications/programs?

Tags: windows-7, system-repair-disc

I haven't done a system repair before, and I'm concerned that the process will alter / screw up my installed applications.

Will I have to reinstall any of my apps/programs, or does Windows 7 system repair leave them intact and untouched?

Comment: What system repair do you mean? Using system *recovery* will indeed revert it to the original factory image.

Comment: Are you referring to System Restore?

Answer (score 0):

System repair only fixes system-related parts, it has nothing to do with the installed applications or programs.

Repair the system, only scan the system folder, restore the illegally modified system files to the default legal version, that is, only affect the system files.
The user's personal files and installed software are not affected.

**References:**

What are the system recovery options in Windows?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17101/windows-7-system-recovery-options

System Recovery Options: Guide for Windows Vista, 7, 8, 8.1 and 10

https://neosmart.net/wiki/system-recovery-options/